# How should I structure my firebase schema to allow for a searching feature

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My schema is as follows:

```
{
   users: {
      user_id_of_who_this_username_belongs_to: {
         bio: {
             name: name1,
             username: test1
         }
      },
      user_id_of_who_this_username_belongs_to: {
         bio: {
             name: name2,
             username: test2
         }
      },

   },
   usernames: {
      test1: user_id_of_who_this_username_belongs_to,
      test2: user_id_of_who_this_username_belongs_to,
   }
}
```

Problem is this schema isn't search friendly, i.e. I want to add a search feature (user enters single word and clicks search) which returns all matching results of users that have that string in their name or username, however, the current schema doesn't allow for that because name can only be accessed if you know the user id.

So my question is how can I edit my current schema to accommodate for this search functionality?

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You should consider removing the node named bio as it is unnecessary here. Your updated database structure should look like the one given below:

[image]

Now you can easily search for users based on their name by using Firebase Query as shown below:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query=databaseReference.child("users").orderByChild("name").equalTo("entered user name");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
           User user =snapshot.getValue(User.class);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

This will work perfectly for a small database, but for a very large database, you can increase the search efficiency by using Firebase Indexing. As you already know that a user will be searched based on his/her name, you can index the name node of users node.

In order to do the required indexing, go to your Firebase console, click on Database and then select RULES tab and edit your rules as shown below:

```
{
  "rules": {
     ".read": "auth != null",
     ".write": "auth != null",

     "users": {
     ".indexOn": ["name"]      
     }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out later today when I have time and get back to you, as far as the bio property I have that because I have another property that I omitted out as a child of the user, i.e.: { user_id: { bio: { ... }, otherProperty: { ... } }. By the way any way you could write that using the JavaScript SDK? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I am not that familiar with JS :(

Answer (score 0):

Your database structure is good but unfortunately, Firebase queries can only `order/filter by a single property`. So there is no `WHERE` clause within Firebase. What should you do instead, is to couple a compound value named `name_username`. Your database structure should look like this:

```
{
   users: {
      user_id_of_who_this_username_belongs_to: {
         name: "name1",
         username: "test1",
         name_username: "name1_test1"
      },
      user_id_of_who_this_username_belongs_to: {
         name: "name2",
         username: "test2",
         name_username: "name2_test2"
      },

   }
}
```

As you probably see, i have added the new compound value `name_username` for each user. This means that you can query your Firebase database according to this new `name_username` field. Note, that i have removed `bio` node, because there is no need for an extra child in your structure. Assuming that `users` node is a direct child of your Firebase root, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String searchedNameOrUserName = "test2";
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name_username = ds.child("name_username").getValue(String.class);
            if(name_username.contains(searchedNameOrUserName)) {
                Log.d("TAG", name_username);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

I gave you an example for searching `test2` keyword. The `searchNameOfUserName` text would be the exact searched name or username typed by the user.

To better understanding, i suggest you see this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs&index=4&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s&t=544s).

You can also use [Denormalization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA) which is normal with the a Firebase Database. Accordingly, you can create another node named `namesUserNames` in which you can add only the desired information after you can search. Your new node should look like this:

```
{
   namesUserNames: {
      user_id_of_who_this_username_belongs_to: {
          name_username: "name1_test1"
      },
      user_id_of_who_this_username_belongs_to: {
          name_username: "name2_test2"
      },
   }
}
```

Using this example, you don't need to download the entire `users` node, you'll be able to download only this particular one. Which saves bandwith.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out later today when I have time and get back to you, as far as the bio property I have that because I have another property that I omitted out as a child of the user, i.e.: { user_id: { bio: { ... }, otherProperty: { ... } }. By the way any way you could write that using the JavaScript SDK? Thanks

Comment: Ok, if you need that `bio` child, just add it after `.child("users")`. Yes there is. I don't know javascript, but the flow is as explained above and in that tutorial.

Comment: Add Javascript a tag to your question.

Comment: doing child("users/bio") doesn't work, nor should it? How would it bypass the user_id? And that tutorial only shows equalsTo whereas I'm looking for matches including substrings

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Should be: `ds.child("bio").child("name_username").getValue(String.class);`. You have bypassed the user_id using `getChildren()` function. In Javascript i think it is: `function(snapshot)`. But Firebase `equalsTo` function doesn't match substring.

Comment: My aim is to make a search for users feature similar to twitter which matches on substring, but, getting all user data client side and querying it is just not practical especially as the user base grows, isn't there like a standard way of accomplishing something like this using firebase?

Comment: Then create another mode in which you can add only the desired data and then attach a listener only at that locatin. This is called denormalization. To a better understanding, please see [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA)

Comment: That's my original question, I asked it to find out if there is already a common solution and a way of structuring a schema to accommodate for this search functionality